# check if JSON data has changed and alert rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to develope a app that checks MYSQL table every minute for new messages and if there is any it should alert the user and show the message. This is the code I use, how should I modify it to make it work?

```
setInterval ( "getMessages()", 60000 );
var oldmessage = "";
function getMessages() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'messages.php?ID=' + ID, function(message) {
       if(JSON.stringify(message) != JSON.stringify(oldmessage)){ // old message is not same as new 
          var messages = data.key[0];
           alert(messages.NEW);
        });



            oldmessage = message;

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is save old message to variable and compare it after minute, and if it has changed I alert row NEW

Comment: umm where is close tag for if statement?

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is, you take a new column in mysql to mark as viewed or not. By default that will be not viewed (say 0). In your PHP code you should retrieve one row which is marked as "Not viewed" or 0. And same you should display via AJAX and update back that row with 1 (viewed).

If you dont receive any rows, send nothing to AJAX and handle the messages accordingly no new rows found.

This is just a logic and hope it helps.